# Style.css not overwriting parent style.css although style.css and functions.php are set up

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

I have been trying to fix this for two days, looking at the different answers on here.

Whenever I edit css in the 'Additional CSS' editor in WP, I get the desired results. However, I can't seem to do this from the style.css sheet. Not that I need to do it from there, but it indicates to me that my child theme is not set up properly.

**My style.css file:**

```
/*
Theme Name: Coblog-child
Template: coblog
Author: [name]
Description: Coblog Child
Version: 1.1.0.1588784301
Updated: 2020-05-06 16:58:21
*/
```

**my functions.php:**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
?>
```

any idea what is wrong within these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only loading the parent-style in your functions.php.
So you do not load the style.css of your child theme.
To make it work, you will have enqueue your child theme's stylesheet as well:

```
function child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css' , array('parent-style'));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_styles' );
```

For the **template** directory uri (parent theme)

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

For the child theme directory uri

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

Comment: Awesome - this seems to have done the trick. Is there a safe way to determine that my child theme is actually set up correctly? I want to avoid any future mistakes. Also, is loading the parent theme style.css supposed to appear in my child theme stylesheet? I would like to edit some of the elements directly in the sheet and wonder if a simple copy paste (of the whole sheet) from parent to child would do. Thanks!

Comment: You would get warnings or errors, if there is something wrong with the themes. - A child theme inherits all style properties and functions of the parent theme. However, individual adjustments in the childtheme overwrite the settings of the original theme. So you don't need to copy over whole parts of the code, the childtheme has the style of the parent. But if you use the same classes or ids, the style properties will be overwritten, because the child comes after the parent styles (code is executed from top to bottom). Please mark the answer as accepted if your are happy with it, thank you :).